# C++ get variable from variable

Tags: c++

Is there another solution, please?

```
if(!http_piconpath && http_tpl)
            { http_piconpath = http_tpl; }
```

If not exist `http_piconpath` but exist `http_tpl` then assign the value from `http_tpl` to `http_piconpath`.

Comment: are these pointers or strings?

Comment: Quality of the question and title is poor. Can you explain what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Please post the whole code and ask the question in an understandable way.Why are you looking for "another solution"? What's wrong with the one you posted? Why?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that both are pointers (of compatible types),

```
if(!http_piconpath) http_piconpath = http_tpl;
```

Or

```
http_piconpath = http_piconpath ? http_piconpath : http_tpl;
```

If picon is null, it gets the value of tpl; if both are null, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

You provide very little information about what you are doing. Assuming that you use strings from your comment, the if statement you've got is not valid for strings, you'll see your compiler screaming that it can't convert string to bool. Below is a very basic example. Note that you must initialise http_piconpath, else it will have a garbage value and you won't know if its value is set or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string http_piconpath = "";
   string http_tpl = "string";

   if(http_piconpath == "" && http_tpl != "") {
       http_piconpath = http_tpl;
   }

   cout << http_piconpath << endl;

   return 0;
}
```